# How to get the last matched text in Flex parser

Tags: flex-lexer

I want match something like:

```
var i=1;
```

So I want to know if `var` has started at word boundary.

When it matches this line I want to know the last character of previous yytext. 
Just to be sure that a char before var is really a non variable character( aka "\b" in regex)

One crude way to maintain `old_yytext` in each rule and also have a default rule ".".

**How to get it?**

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to save a copy of the previous token, or at least the last character. Flex's buffer management strategy does not guarantee that the previous token still exists in memory. It is possible that the current token starts at the beginning of flex's buffer.

But doing the work of saving the previous token in every rule would be really silly. You should trust flex to work as advertised, and write appropriate rules. For example, if your identifier pattern looks like this:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*
```

then it is impossible for `var` to immediately follow an identifier because it would have been included in the idebtifier.

There is one common case in a "normal" flex scanner definition where a keyword or identifier might immediately follow an alphanumeric character, which is when the keyword immediately follows a number (`123var`). This is not usually a problem, because in almost all languages, it will trigger a syntax error (and if it isn't a syntax error, maybe it is ok :-) )

If you really want to trigger a lexical error, you can add a pattern which recognizes a number followed by a letter.